# Where can I find graywater reuse quality thresholds for different uses?

Tags: water, waste-water, greywater

I'm having a hard time finding specific up-to-date sources that contain clear guidelines and regulatory quality thresholds for graywater reuse. The only thing I could find was the EPA 2012 report and the WHO 2006 volumes, but I can't seem to find other sources, especially for Germany, France, Singapore, Spain, and other countries.

Does anyone know of any good resources for what I'm looking for?

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! What's the intended usage? Consumption?
I think it's a topic the European Commission is working on; if you [search here](https://ec.europa.eu/search/index.do?queryText=water+reuse+quality+consumption)
you'll find all kinds of documents. 
BTW asking for a (potential) long list of things is generally not a good fit for this website and such questions may be closed.

Comment: I was looking for a documents that has " for usage 1, say toilet flushing, these are the allowed or preferable thresholds". Thank you so much for your help! i'll keep the question format in check next time :). On another note, would you recommend working with a country's general reclaimed wastewater quality thresholds if i didn't find anything specific to graywater regulations ?

Comment: Without knowing more what your goal is and where and when you intent to reuse the water we really cannot recommend anything. Feel free to ask another question about this, but please keep in mind that good questions focus on the problem you are trying to solve and should be objectively answerable.

Comment: Take a look at the [International Plumbing Code](https://www.iccsafe.org/content/international-plumbing-code-ipc-home-page/) (which, despite it's name, mostly applies to the US). They also list other relevant codes: BOCA National Plumbing Code, SBCCI Standard Plumbing Code, and ICBO Plumbing Code.

Comment: I have edited this slightly, but I think it would be better if this question were to be reworded to ask what the guidelines are (or what the differences are between guidelines in different countries or regions), and then specify that you want them backed up by official sources, rather than asking specifically for off-site guidelines. I can help with this if you want?

Comment: A lot of Stack Exchange sites dislike questions that ask directly for off-site resources, 1) because it seems to be a bit of an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/179041) (i.e. if you need the resources (Y) because you're having some problem (X) - you should ask about X instead). and 2) any answer that simply links to off-site resources, will be useless when those resources are moved or deleted.